# I've ran into a logical problem with my card finder, been stuck for some days

Tags: javascript, html, card

I am new to Javascript and programming in general. I've done some simple projects and right now I'm working on a card finder. The user inputs how many cards they have, and then inputs how many remaining cards they have and the system displays the missing one. (eg. I have 5 cards in total. My remaining cards are 1, 2, 4, 5. The missing card is 3). It works all fine until the user inserts their remaining card (last one), then it alerts a VERY BIG negative or positive number.

```js
// Declaring the variables required to find the missing card
var amountOfCards, numOfCards, result, cards, missingCard, remainingCards, resultOfMissingCard;

// Assigning result and cards variables
result = 0;
cards = 1;

// Asking the user how many cards they have
amountOfCards = prompt('How many cards do you have?');

// Changing the number of cards or numOfCards to an integer 
numOfCards = parseInt(amountOfCards);

// Finding the missing card equation
missingCard = (amountOfCards*(amountOfCards+1))/2;

// While loop
while (cards < numOfCards) {
    remainingCards = prompt('What card do you have remaining?') // This line is for the user to enter their remaining cards
    cards = parseInt(remainingCards);
    result = result + parseInt(remainingCards);
    cards++;
}

// Finding the missing card
resultOfMissingCard = result - missingCard;

// Alerting the user of their missing card
alert('Your missing card is ' + resultOfMissingCard);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="./findingthemissingcard.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

I appreciate you guys if you can help me. Again, I am no pro. Really new. I think there is a problem in:

resultOfMissingCard = result - missingCard

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this.

```
var amountOfCards, numOfCards, result, cards, missingCard, remainingCards, resultOfMissingCard;

result = 0;
cards = 1;


amountOfCards = prompt('How many cards do you have?');

numOfCards = parseInt(amountOfCards);


missingCard = (numOfCards*(numOfCards+1))/2;


while (cards <= numOfCards) {
    remainingCards = prompt('What card do you have remaining?') 
    cards = parseInt(remainingCards);
    result = result + parseInt(remainingCards);
    cards++;
}


resultOfMissingCard = missingCard - result;


alert('Your missing card is ' + resultOfMissingCard);
```

You forgot to use `numOfCards` which is a int converted from string in the equation to find the missing card instead you used the actual string inputted by the user. And also in the while loop you have to compare `cards <= numOfCards`. Also in the end you just had to subtract result from missingCard.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you already got an answer I improved a bit on the calculation, and made it possible to type in the cards that you still have in any order. The script is also a lot shorter as you can see.

```
var stillgot = [], real = 0, cards = prompt("how many cards did you have")

for (var i = 0; i < cards - 1; i++) {
    stillgot.push(parseInt(prompt("Enter a card you still have")))
}

var expected = (parseInt(cards)*(parseInt(cards)+1))/2

for(var i = 0; i < stillgot.length; i++){
    real = (real + parseInt(stillgot[i]))
}

var res = (expected - real)

alert("You are missing card " + res)
```